# what actually the sigmoid derivative purpose?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-science, derivative, sigmoid

Honestly im learning the neural network but i have a question in the activation part.
I know that the question is general and a lot of explanation around the internet. But i still don't understand clearly.

> Why we need to derivate the sigmoid function?  why do not we just use
>   it?

It will be good if you give the clear explanation. Thankyou.
I've seen many videos on youtube, i've read many article about it but still don't get it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I assume you are asking: "Why don't we just use the Sigmoid function without having to calculate its derivative?".

Your question is also very broad, so my answer is very broad and wordy, you will need to read more to understand all the details, for which I'll try to provide links.

1. **Activation function**: as the name suggests, we are wanting to know if a given node is "on" or "off", for which the sigmoid function provides an easy way to turn continuous variables (X) into a range of {0,1}.

   [image: formula]

Use cases can vary and this function has certain properties, and so that is why there are many alternative "activation" functions, like *tanh*, *ReLU*, etc. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

2. **Differentiate (derivate)**: most models we want to find the best-fit beta parameters for all our activation functions. To do this we, we typically want to minimise a "cost" function that describes how good our model is at predicting observed data. One way to solve this optimisation problem is Gradient Descent. Each step of gradient descent updates the parameters by following the multi-dimensional cost-function space. To do this, it needs the gradient of the activation function. This is important for back propagation that uses gradient descent to optimise the network, it requires that the activation functions you use (in most cases) to be differentiateable.
   Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent

I suggest if you have a deeper question that you take it to one of the machine learning stackexchange sites.